# Universal Windows Platform app freezes when using Secure Storage on Xamarin Essentials

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I'm adding Secure Storage by using Xamarin Essentials, but the app keeps freezing (no errors) every time I try to save on Universal Windows Platform (UWP).  Can someone explain why it is freezing?

Note: I have this working on Android devices with no problems.

```
try
{
   await SecureStorage.SetAsync("username", Username.Text);
   await SecureStorage.SetAsync("password", Password.Text);
}
catch (Exception){}
```

According to this [form](https://According%20to%20microsoft%20for%20windows%20there%20is%20nothing%20I%20need%20to%20srtup%20before%20using) there is no setup needed before using Secure Storage on UWP.

Comment: I have test your code, but I could not reproduce your issue, Please make sure you installed  `Xamarin Essentials` nuget package for your uwp client project and the uwp target version higher than 16299. for more detail please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/get-started?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=windows%2Cios).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The threaded was being locked up so I had to to add `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` so the code ends up looking like this:

```
try
{
  Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>{
   await SecureStorage.SetAsync("username", Username.Text);
   await SecureStorage.SetAsync("password", Password.Text);
  });
}
catch (Exception){}
```

Comment: I have been working on this issue for 3 hours and desperately trying to find possible solutions. Could you please explain a little more so I can understand better?

Answer (score 0):

I had similiar problem. Code was working for iOS and Android, but failing for UWP (blocking the app). [Understanding Async, Avoiding Deadlocks in C#](https://medium.com/rubrikkgroup/understanding-async-avoiding-deadlocks-e41f8f2c6f5d) article shed light on that issue. It explains reasons why app could be blocked, and how to handle it porperly.